# What is the function of the TransferFunc in Volume Rendering using GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, volume-rendering

I have a problem in Volume Rendering using GLSL. The source code can be found in the following link https://github.com/toolchainX/Volume_Rendering_Using_GLSL. In the fragment shader named `raycasting.frag`, sampler1D `TransferFunc` appears, but I do not know the actual function(usage or meaning) of `TransferFunc`. Below are the details of raycasting.frag.

And the concrete code is: **colorSample = texture(TransferFunc, intensity);**

```
#version 400
in vec3 EntryPoint;
in vec4 ExitPointCoord;

uniform sampler2D ExitPoints;
uniform sampler3D VolumeTex;
uniform sampler1D TransferFunc;  
uniform float     StepSize;
uniform vec2      ScreenSize;
layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    // ExitPointCoord 的坐标是设备规范化坐标
    // 出现了和纹理坐标有关的问题。
    vec3 exitPoint = texture(ExitPoints, gl_FragCoord.st/ScreenSize).xyz;
    // that will actually give you clip-space coordinates rather than
    // normalised device coordinates, since you're not performing the perspective
    // division which happens during the rasterisation process (between the vertex
    // shader and fragment shader
    // vec2 exitFragCoord = (ExitPointCoord.xy / ExitPointCoord.w + 1.0)/2.0;
    // vec3 exitPoint  = texture(ExitPoints, exitFragCoord).xyz;
    if (EntryPoint == exitPoint)
        //background need no raycasting
        discard;
    vec3 dir = exitPoint - EntryPoint;
    float len = length(dir); // the length from front to back is calculated and used to terminate the ray
    vec3 deltaDir = normalize(dir) * StepSize;
    float deltaDirLen = length(deltaDir);
    vec3 voxelCoord = EntryPoint;
    vec4 colorAcum = vec4(0.0); // The dest color
    float alphaAcum = 0.0;                // The  dest alpha for blending
    /* 定义颜色查找的坐标 */
    float intensity;
    float lengthAcum = 0.0;
    vec4 colorSample; // The src color 
    float alphaSample; // The src alpha
    // backgroundColor
    vec4 bgColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1600; i++){
        // 获得体数据中的标量值scaler value
        intensity =  texture(VolumeTex, voxelCoord).x;
        // 查找传输函数中映射后的值
        // 依赖性纹理读取  
        colorSample = texture(TransferFunc, intensity);
        // modulate the value of colorSample.a
        // front-to-back integration
        if (colorSample.a > 0.0) {
            // accomodate for variable sampling rates (base interval defined by mod_compositing.frag)
            colorSample.a = 1.0 - pow(1.0 - colorSample.a, StepSize*200.0f);
            colorAcum.rgb += (1.0 - colorAcum.a) * colorSample.rgb * colorSample.a;
            colorAcum.a += (1.0 - colorAcum.a) * colorSample.a;
        }
        voxelCoord += deltaDir;
        lengthAcum += deltaDirLen;
        if (lengthAcum >= len ){    
            colorAcum.rgb = colorAcum.rgb*colorAcum.a + (1 - colorAcum.a)*bgColor.rgb;      
            break;  // terminate if opacity > 1 or the ray is outside the volume    
        }else if (colorAcum.a > 1.0){
            colorAcum.a = 1.0;
            break;
        }
    }
    FragColor = colorAcum;
    // for test
    // FragColor = vec4(EntryPoint, 1.0);
    // FragColor = vec4(exitPoint, 1.0);

}
```

I hope you can help me to solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function determines how an intensity from the 3D volume dataset is mapped to a color.

Many 3D datasets, for example from medical imaging, contain a single value per voxel. For example, for a CT scan, this would be the amount of X-ray absorption (at least that's what I think it is...).

When you render the 3D dataset, you want to encode different intensities as different colors. That's what the transfer function does. If you use a 1D texture to encode the transfer function, this texture will contain a RGBA color for each possible intensity value.

These transfer functions can be anything you want to make the resulting image look good/useful. Very typical transfer functions have the form:

- Completely transparent (alpha = 0.0) below a certain intensity value.
- Linear ramp, with alpha increasing from 0.0 to 1.0, for a range of values above that. For best visual results, this often includes the use of 3 different colors. For example, black at alpha = 0.0, red at alpha = 0.5, and white at alpha = 1.0, with colors interpolated between these values.
- Completely opaque (alpha = 1.0) above that.

If your image data is read from a DICOM file, it can contain tags that tell you the range of values that should be used for these different parts of the transfer function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a question. If the intensity is in the range: 0 to 255, the transfer functions are not necessary, am I right? What's more, my work has something to do with the DICOM files and it seems that you are familiar with DICOM files, can I have your email to ask some detailed questions to you? Thank you!

Comment: @Hurricane: That's a matter of interpretation. You ***can*** map the intensity of each voxel directly to gray scale but even that is already an application of a transfer function, namely the identity for each color channel.

Comment: @thokra: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hurricane Agree with thokra, you can try that. Depending on the data, you will get something that looks somewhat reasonable, or it could happen that uninteresting parts with low intensity hide all the interesting structure in the data. Choosing a good transfer function is critical in getting really nice looking volume rendering.

Comment: @Hurricane I'd rather not post my email address here. Even though it's fairly easy to guess... If you want, you can get in touch on LinkedIn.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: "Even though it's fairly easy to guess", what does it mean? And what is LinkedIn? Thank you!

Comment: @Hurricane You never heard of LinkedIn? It's a professional network with over 400 million members. Among other things, it has become one of the primary places where hiring for tech jobs happens.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Because I am Chinese, I never heard of LinkedIn. But I want to learn something from you, can you tell me how can I get in touch with you on LinkedIn?